# Could not load [META-INF/frontend/lumo-includes.ts]

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, spring-boot, hilla

After upgrading to hilla 2, I got run time error,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/frontend/lumo-includes.ts]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.

I just create a new project using vs code

1. `npx @hilla/cli init --react my-hilla-app`
2. compile it using `mvn clean install`
3. run it using `mnvw`

at run time,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/frontend/lumo-includes.ts]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1457) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1047) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.scanner.ClassFinder$DefaultClassFinder.getResource(ClassFinder.java:105) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.scanner.ClassFinder$CachedClassFinder.getResource(ClassFinder.java:159) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateImports$UpdateMainImportsFile.getResource(TaskUpdateImports.java:181) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.hasMetaInfResource(AbstractUpdateImports.java:573) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.resolveResource(AbstractUpdateImports.java:264) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.lambda$resolveModules$1(AbstractUpdateImports.java:192) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.resolveModules(AbstractUpdateImports.java:193) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.collectModules(AbstractUpdateImports.java:289) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.AbstractUpdateImports.run(AbstractUpdateImports.java:102) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskUpdateImports.execute(TaskUpdateImports.java:362) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]  
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:301) ~[flow-server-24.0.0.jar:24.0.0]
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:372) ~[vaadin-dev-server-24.0.0.jar:na]
        at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:313) ~[vaadin-dev-server-24.0.0.jar:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Was this a one time error or does it reproduce on every startup?

Comment: Dear Artur, thanks for your support. This error occurred when compiled with 'mvn clean install' and then 'mvn spring-boot:run'. Otherwise if run without compile, the error will not happen

Comment: The real error is probably above that stacktrace as it says "this web application instance has been stopped already". The problem is that the application instance has been stopped too early, for some other reason